# Python Pandas - how to get top n values and the sum of all other values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
Browsers        Sessions
Chrome          201
IE              136
Safari          101
Firefox         36
SamsungBrowse   12
Opera           6
```

and what I need is display top 3 values and sum the rest as 'other':

```
Browsers        Sessions
Chrome          201
IE              136
Safari          101
Other           54
```

Any ideas how this could be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [39]: result = df.nlargest(3, columns='Sessions')

In [40]: result.loc[len(result)] = ['Others', df.loc[~df.Browsers.isin(result.Browsers), 'Sessions'].sum()]

In [41]: result
Out[41]:
  Browsers  Sessions
0   Chrome       201
1       IE       136
2   Safari       101
3   Others        54
```

Answer (score 5):

There can be better ways to do this. But one way can be like this:

```
df2 = df.sort_values('Sessions', ascending=False)[:3]
s = df.sort_values('Sessions', ascending=False).Sessions[3:].sum()
df3.loc[len(df2)]=['Others', s]
print df3
```

Output:

```
  Browsers  Sessions
0   Chrome       201
1       IE       136
2   Safari       101
3   Others        54
```