# Select top N rows by a specific sum value of one column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataframe like this (I copy example dataframe from link in the end):

```
Browsers        Sessions
Chrome          201
IE              136
Safari          101
Firefox         36
SamsungBrowse   12
Opera           6
```

I want **top N rows** of the sum value of `Sessions` is less than a given number say **500**? How can achieve that in Python? Thanks.

```
Browsers        Sessions
Chrome          201
IE              136
Safari          101
```

This is what I have tried:

```
df = df[df['Session'].sum(axis=1) > 500]
```

Here is a link for reference and where the example data I got.

[Python Pandas - how to get top n values and the sum of all other values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329031/python-pandas-how-to-get-top-n-values-and-the-sum-of-all-other-values)

Comment: Please post the code where you have self attempted to solve this

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then use `nlargest`:

```
df = df[df['Sessions'] < 500].nlargest(3, columns='Sessions')
#alternative for filtering
#df = df.query('Sessions < 500').nlargest(3, columns='Sessions')
```

Or [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
df = df[df['Sessions'] < 500].sort_values('Sessions', ascending=False).head(3)
```

---

```
print (df)
  Browsers  Sessions
0   Chrome       201
1       IE       136
2   Safari       101
```

EDIT:

```
df = df.sort_values('Sessions', ascending=False)

print (df['Sessions'].cumsum())
0    201
1    337
2    438
3    474
4    486
5    492
Name: Sessions, dtype: int64

df = df[df['Sessions'].cumsum() < 450]
print (df)
  Browsers  Sessions
0   Chrome       201
1       IE       136
2   Safari       101
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe your solution just select rows by the value of Sessions? I hope to select rows by the sum value of Sessions.

Comment: @ahbon - not sure if understand, `df['Session'].sum(axis=1)` return `ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`, do you think sum while is not sum `500` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. cumsum() function is what i'm looking for.